# Why does SELECT find queries but UPDATE updates none on the same WHERE?

Tags: mysql, null

I have the strangest problem - when i run:

```
SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `translation` = ''
```

i get: `Showing rows 0 - 29 (6,925 total, Query took 0.0008 sec)`

but when I run:

```
UPDATE `words` SET `translation`= NULL WHERE `translation`= ''
```

I get: `0 row(s) affected. ( Query took 0.2200 sec )`

why doesn't it want to udpate the rows? It is the same WHERE clause.

Comment: maybe the column definition is not allowing NULL values? check the table design.

Comment: @mgPePe : use command `DESCRIBE words` and let us know what you get.

Comment: @tpaksu: it would be a error in that case

Comment: Or could be a lack of privileges.

Comment: I'd have expected this on Oracle, but MySQL treats null as different from an empty string as per SQL92 (and I've just checked that 5.0.67 still does)

Comment: @tpaksu  - YES! that was it, the table would not allow NULL. can you please write the answer so i mark it as right?

Comment: actually, even after allowing NULL value, it wouldn't update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, try this:

```
UPDATE words SET translation='$$$' WHERE translation = '';
UPDATE words SET translation=NULL WHERE translation = '$$$';
```

and secondly; maybe the column definition is not allowing NULL values? check the table design.

Comment: did you change the table design before testing that? unless you did that, it still won't work.

Comment: yes, i updated so it can take NULL values, but still it didn't work directly, i had to go through $$$, why was that?

Comment: I don't know. maybe there aren't any "" values left because you once executed the query.

Comment: I rechecked the SELECT and they were there... oh well. this trick did it though

Answer (score 3):

Is `translation` declared as `not null`, with default value `''`? If so, setting it to `NULL` with an `UPDATE` has no effect, and MySQL correctly reports that no rows were changed. That is, you are doing the equivalent of `UPDATE words SET translation = 'a' WHERE translation = 'a'`.

You should get warnings, though. The MySQL command-line client reports warnings like this:

```
mysql> UPDATE words SET translation=NULL WHERE translation = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 0  Warnings: 2
```

To see the warnings use the command `show warnings;`:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                             |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1048 | Column 'translation' cannot be null |
| Warning | 1048 | Column 'translation' cannot be null |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you don't allow `translation` column to be `NULL`. Does it return

```
Error Code: 1048
Column 'translation` cannot be null
```

when you execute the statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think translation allows null, If it is os try this

```
 UPDATE `words` SET `translation`= NULL WHERE `translation IS NULL.
```

Answer (score -1):

try using some other column like ID or something

```
update 'words' set 'translation'=null where id in (select id from 'words' where 'translation'=''
```

NO idea though why this is happening.